# Problema al obtener los datos de una columna Laravel 8

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

Estoy tratando de obtener los valores de una columna en el "Model" de una tabla en "Laravel 8", con "select" y dos "where" anidados, pero no consigo que me devuelva bien los datos en forma de vector.

Este sería el "Model":

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Database\Factories\ImpartFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Impart extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'impart';
    protected $fillable = ['course_id', 'group_words', 'subject', 'teacher'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function group() {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Group', ['course_id', 'group_words']);
    }

    public function subject() {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Subject', 'subject');
    }

    public function teacher() {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Teacher', 'teacher');
    }

    public static function getByCourseGroup($courseId, $groupWords) {
        return Impart::where('course_id', '=', $courseId) -> where('group_words', '=', $groupWords) -> get();
    }

    public static function getTeachers($courseId, $groupWords) {
        return Impart::select('teacher') -> where('course_id', '=', $courseId)
            -> where('group_words', '=', $groupWords) -> get();
    }

    protected static function newFactory(): ImpartFactory {
        return ImpartFactory::new();
    }
}
```

El método con el cual estoy teniendo problemas es:

```
public static function getTeachers($courseId, $groupWords) {
    return Impart::select('teacher') -> where('course_id', '=', $courseId)
        -> where('group_words', '=', $groupWords) -> get();
}
```

La invocación es la siguiente:

```
$teachers = Impart::getTeachers($student[0] -> course_id, $student[0] -> group_words);
```

Y la respuesta que muestro usando:

```
$output->writeln($teachers);
```

Es:

[image: Respuesta de consola]

No se si realmente es posible recuperar en un array los valores de la columna "teacher" sin tener que recuperar la columna "subject" también. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: No comprendo como necesitas obtener los datos, es decir, ¿cómo debería ser la salida?

Comment: Necesitaría recuperar un vector, algo como: ["1111111A", "22222222B", "33333333C",...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la función pluck de collections de laravel

```
$output->writeln($teachers->pluck('teacher'));
```

Comment: Desconocía la función pluck, me ha servido, muchísimas gracias.